# Fourth degree complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

The exercise is in my language so I'll do my best to translate it to English

> Find all different complex numbers $z$ that make $z^4 = (1-2i)^4$.

How do I solve this?

Simplifying the equation yields $z^4 = -7+24i$ but that's as far as I can get.

Comment: Solve $w^4=1$ where $w=\dfrac{z}{1-2i}$.

Answer (score 0):

The complete solution set is given by $z=\omega(1-2i)$, where $\omega^4=1$. Consider all four distinct fourth roots of unity.